# Coding style for a single line, 1 time used function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, coding-style

I have this line of code in a react component. This is the only place in the whole component which calls the `editSection` prop and that is why I have used a function expression inside the onClick instead of defining a separate function.

```
<Link to={SOME_PATH} onClick={() => editSection(sectionID)}>
```

Is this a good coding practice or I should have defined a function and called it from onClick. I know the technical differences between both scenarios but not sure which best suites the coding standards. Also, is there any performance implication between both styles?

Comment: Why are you defining a function that calls a function instead of just calling the function? What about giving a `data-` style parameter for `sectionID`?

Answer (score 2):

As for best practice, Using an arrow function tends to be most performant and in a general rule is the best practice. https://medium.freecodecamp.org/the-best-way-to-bind-event-handlers-in-react-282db2cf1530 and many more resources encourage you to use arrow functions when possible and in most cases is the proper approach.

I also like that you are passing in the parameter of sectionID taking full advantage of how react does things instead of using the data attribute then having to us JS to pull the id out of the React element.

Answer (score 0):

You can just call it as referenced in [the documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/handling-events.html) under "Passing Arguments to Event Handlers":

```
<Link to={SOME_PATH} onClick={this.editSection.bind(this, sectionID)}>
```

You may want to express it a little differently to make this more modular:

```
<Link to={SOME_PATH} onClick={editSection} data-sectionID={sectionID}>
```

So then your `editSection` can pull the associated `data` value(s) to do its thing.

Comment: When I call the `editSection` directly, Browser doesn't recognize it as a function and throws an error saying react expected a function but instead found an object as the parameter. I have tried both ways that you mentioned but it didn't work. Also, I never came across the `data-` syntax and my browser throws error.

Comment: What error? The [`data-` property is a valid HTML attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Howto/Use_data_attributes), so it's worth noting the exact error you get. On Stack Overflow try to avoid saying "I get an error" and instead paste in the error you actually get.